# Responsive Textbox in bootstrap for extra small size(col-xs) not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Hello friends the textbox is working fine when the size is large, medium and small, but when I the textbox in extra small sized device then it is getting cut. Following is the code for my text field. Please help me out with this, every help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
<div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 control-label" style="">Anything</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-9 col-xs-12 col-md-9">
                               <div class="input-group">
                                  <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                             <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label" style="">per</label> 
                             <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default tax_percentage active" > month </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default tax_flat"> year </button>
                                <input type='hidden' id='month_year_button' name='month_year_button' />
                             </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
                             <p>How much will spend on office rent?</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be working here

Comment: Hello @Kay it is not working in my form don't know why.

Comment: Could you please post an image of your current result, and the prolonged result?

Comment: seems to be working here too.  I just created a jsFiddle, could you go into more detail about what you are looking for?  http://jsfiddle.net/e0m23hf6/

Comment: Hi @Kay please check out the screenshot which I have taken. Thanks

Comment: I'm using the same code which I have posted above

Comment: The above code is working well. It might be you need to refresh the page when you click on "Toggle device mode" button in chrome browser.

Comment: Hello Amol Please check out the code now, I have posted the complete code for that row

Answer (score 1):

you should decrease the size of the column for xs so that they all fit in a single row.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-8">
<label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-xs-4 col-md-3 control-label" style="">Anything</label>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-9 col-xs-8 col-md-9 input-sm">
<label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount"></label>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

hope this works for you.

Comment: Hello @dup.titung thanks but I have two columns, let me edit my main code and show you

Comment: you can give both divs and xs col of 12 or greater that 6 so they make 2 rows. and then give col of 6 for label and input div, same on the next column.